# What is the proper way to send an HTTP 404 response from an ASP.NET MVC action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

If given the route:

**{FeedName}/{ItemPermalink}**

ex: /Blog/Hello-World

If the item doesn't exist, I want to return a 404. What is the right way to do this in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question btw. This is going in my standard project additions :D

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Shooting from the hip (cowboy coding ;-)), I'd suggest something like this:

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult("This doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

---

**HttpNotFoundResult:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourNamespaceHere
{
    /// <summary>An implementation of <see cref="ActionResult" /> that throws an <see cref="HttpException" />.</summary>
    public class HttpNotFoundResult : ActionResult
    {
        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of <see cref="HttpNotFoundResult" /> with the specified <paramref name="message"/>.</summary>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        public HttpNotFoundResult(String message)
        {
            this.Message = message;
        }

        /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of <see cref="HttpNotFoundResult" /> with an empty message.</summary>
        public HttpNotFoundResult()
            : this(String.Empty) { }

        /// <summary>Gets or sets the message that will be passed to the thrown <see cref="HttpException" />.</summary>
        public String Message { get; set; }

        /// <summary>Overrides the base <see cref="ActionResult.ExecuteResult" /> functionality to throw an <see cref="HttpException" />.</summary>
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            throw new HttpException((Int32)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, this.Message);
        }
    }
}
// By Erik van Brakel, with edits from Daniel Schaffer :)
```

Using this approach you comply to the framework standards. There already is a HttpUnauthorizedResult in there, so this would simply extend the framework in the eyes of another developer maintaining your code later on (you know, the psycho who knows where you live).

You could use reflector to take a look into the assembly to see how the HttpUnauthorizedResult is achieved, because I don't know if this approach misses anything (it seems too simple almost).

---

I did use reflector to take a look at the HttpUnauthorizedResult just now. Seems they're setting the StatusCode on the response to 0x191 (401). Although this works for 401, using 404 as the new value I seem to be getting just a blank page in Firefox. Internet Explorer shows a default 404 though (not the ASP.NET version). Using the webdeveloper toolbar I inspected the headers in FF, which DO show a 404 Not Found response. Could be simply something I misconfigured in FF.

---

This being said, I think Jeff's approach is a fine example of KISS. If you don't really need the verbosity in this sample, his method works fine as well.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the Enum as well. As I said, it's just a crude example, feel free to improve upon it. This is supposed to be a knowledgebase after all ;-)

Comment: I think I went a bit overboard... enjoy :D

Comment: FWIW, Jeff's example also requires that you have a custom 404 page.

Comment: One problem with throwing HttpException instead of just setting the HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404 is if you use OnException Controller handler (as I do), it will catch the HttpExceptions too. So I think just setting the StatusCode is a better approach.

Comment: HttpException or HttpNotFoundResult in MVC3 is useful in many way. In case of @Igor Brejc, just use **if** statement in the OnException to filter out the not found error.

Answer (score 47):

We do it like so; this code is found in `BaseController`

```
/// <summary>
/// returns our standard page not found view
/// </summary>
protected ViewResult PageNotFound()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View("PageNotFound");
}
```

called like so

```
public ActionResult ShowUserDetails(int? id)
{        
    // make sure we have a valid ID
    if (!id.HasValue) return PageNotFound();
```

Comment: is this action then wired up to a default route? Can't see how it gets to get executed.

Comment: Could be running it like this:
 protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
{
     PageNotFound().ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
}

Comment: I used to do it that way, but found that splitting the result and the view displayed was a better approach. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 19):

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Are you sure you're in the right place?");
```

Comment: I like this because it follows the custom error pages set up in `web.config`.

Answer (score 7):

The HttpNotFoundResult is a great first step to what I am using. Returning an HttpNotFoundResult is good. Then the question is, what's next?

I created an action filter called HandleNotFoundAttribute that then shows a 404 error page. Since it returns a view, you can create a special 404 view per controller, or let is use a default shared 404 view. This will even be called when a controller doesn't have the specified action present, because the framework throws an HttpException with a status code of 404.

```
public class HandleNotFoundAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpException = filterContext.Exception.GetBaseException() as HttpException;
        if (httpException != null && httpException.GetHttpCode() == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; // Prevents IIS from intercepting the error and displaying its own content.
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                                        {
                                            ViewName = "404",
                                            ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData,
                                            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                                        };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that as of MVC3, you can just use `HttpStatusCodeResult`.

Comment: Or, even easier, `HttpNotFoundResult`

Answer (score 6):

Using **ActionFilter** is **hard to maintain** because whenever we throw an error the filter need to be set in the attribute. What if we forget to set it? One way is deriving `OnException` on base controller. You need to define a `BaseController` derived from `Controller` and all your controllers must derive from `BaseController`. It is a best practise to have a base controller.

Note if using `Exception` the response status code is 500, so we need to change it to 404 for Not Found and 401 for Unauthorized. Just like I mention above, use `OnException` overrides on `BaseController` to avoid using filter attribute.

The new MVC 3 also make more troublesome by returning an empty view to browser. The best solution after some research is based on my answer here [How to return a view for HttpNotFound() in ASP.Net MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985550/how-to-return-a-view-for-httpnotfound-in-asp-net-mvc-3/5254840#5254840)

To make more convinience I paste it here:

---

After some study. The workaround for **MVC 3** here is to derive all `HttpNotFoundResult`, `HttpUnauthorizedResult`, `HttpStatusCodeResult` classes and implement **new** (overriding it) `HttpNotFound`() method in `BaseController`.

It is best practise to use base Controller so you have 'control' over all derived Controllers.

I create new `HttpStatusCodeResult` class, not to derive from `ActionResult` but from `ViewResult` to render the view or any `View` you want by specifying the `ViewName` property. I follow the original `HttpStatusCodeResult` to set the `HttpContext.Response.StatusCode` and `HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription` but then `base.ExecuteResult(context)` will render the suitable view because again I derive from `ViewResult`. Simple enough is it? Hope this will be implemented in the MVC core.

See my `BaseController` bellow:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YourNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public BaseController()
        {
            ViewBag.MetaDescription = Settings.metaDescription;
            ViewBag.MetaKeywords = Settings.metaKeywords;
        }

        protected new HttpNotFoundResult HttpNotFound(string statusDescription = null)
        {
            return new HttpNotFoundResult(statusDescription);
        }

        protected HttpUnauthorizedResult HttpUnauthorized(string statusDescription = null)
        {
            return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(statusDescription);
        }

        protected class HttpNotFoundResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
        {
            public HttpNotFoundResult() : this(null) { }

            public HttpNotFoundResult(string statusDescription) : base(404, statusDescription) { }

        }

        protected class HttpUnauthorizedResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
        {
            public HttpUnauthorizedResult(string statusDescription) : base(401, statusDescription) { }
        }

        protected class HttpStatusCodeResult : ViewResult
        {
            public int StatusCode { get; private set; }
            public string StatusDescription { get; private set; }

            public HttpStatusCodeResult(int statusCode) : this(statusCode, null) { }

            public HttpStatusCodeResult(int statusCode, string statusDescription)
            {
                this.StatusCode = statusCode;
                this.StatusDescription = statusDescription;
            }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                if (context == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
                }

                context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = this.StatusCode;
                if (this.StatusDescription != null)
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = this.StatusDescription;
                }
                // 1. Uncomment this to use the existing Error.ascx / Error.cshtml to view as an error or
                // 2. Uncomment this and change to any custom view and set the name here or simply
                // 3. (Recommended) Let it commented and the ViewName will be the current controller view action and on your view (or layout view even better) show the @ViewBag.Message to produce an inline message that tell the Not Found or Unauthorized
                //this.ViewName = "Error";
                this.ViewBag.Message = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription;
                base.ExecuteResult(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use in your action like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Some processing
    if (...)
        return HttpNotFound();
    // Other processing
}
```

And in _Layout.cshtml (like master page)

```
<div class="content">
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div class="inlineMsg"><p>@ViewBag.Message</p></div>
    }
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Additionally you can use a custom view like `Error.shtml` or create new `NotFound.cshtml` like I commented in the code and you may define a view model for the status description and other explanations.

Comment: You can always register a global filter which beats a base controller because you have to REMEMBER to use your base controller!

Comment: :) Not sure either this is still an issue in MVC4. What I mean at that time is the HandleNotFoundAttribute filter answered by someone else. It is not necessary to be applied for each actions. E.g. it only suitable for action that has id param but not Index() action. I agreed on global filter, not for HandleNotFoundAttribute but a custom HandleErrorAttribute.

Comment: I thought MVC3 had it too, not sure. Good discussion regardless for others that may come across the answer