# CustomErrors vs HttpErrors - A significant design flaw?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

As we might know, from e.g. [What is the difference between customErrors and httpErrors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2480006/681538), [CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a older way to define error pages in a web application but this approach have some issues - for example if you care about correct http response codes since the approach of CustomErrors is to redirect to an error page instead of replacing the current response, which destroys most of the semantic integrity of the communication by http status codes.

[HttpErrors](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors) is a newer feature available since IIS 7.0 which is running on the server level instead of the application level, and is much better suited to handle error responses in a valid way, for example by using the current response instead of redirecting.

However, if seems to me that the infrastructure for these artifacts in ASP.NET as it looks today gives us some problem.

**A simple configuration as example**

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Auto" errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/E404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

We set *errorMode* to *Custom* because we want to test the error handling itself, and we set *existingResponse* to *Auto*, which will introduce a branch dependent on [Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

- **True**: the existing erroneous response will pass through this module unhandled, which makes total sense considering it's semantic meaning.
- **False**: the existing erroneous response will be replaced by the HttpErrors module if it has a matching rule, which makes just as much sense.

This would *ideally* allow us to handle some errors ourselves, like when the product in *../product/id* does not exist, where we can manually can return a specific 404 page with information about missing products and still let the HttpErrors module handle all the rest like *../products/namebutshouldbeid* or just *../misspelledandunmatchableurl*.

However, as far as I can see, this is not working. The reason is in the internal method *[System.Web.HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx).ReportRuntimeError*, which will be called on runtime errors (e.g. controllers/actions not found) and where we have a section that looks like this:

```
// always try to disable IIS custom errors when we send an error
if (_wr != null) {
    _wr.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
}

if (!localExecute) {
code = HttpException.GetHttpCodeForException(e);

// Don't raise event for 404.  See VSWhidbey 124147.
if (code != 404) {
    WebBaseEvent.RaiseRuntimeError(e, this);
}

// This cannot use the HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled property, since it must call
// GetSettings() with the canThrow parameter.
customErrorsSetting = CustomErrorsSection.GetSettings(_context, canThrow);
if (customErrorsSetting != null)
    useCustomErrors = customErrorsSetting.CustomErrorsEnabled(Request);
else
    useCustomErrors = true;
}
```

While first debugging this I saw that *useCustomErrors* was set to false, and I could not understand why since I knew that I had a working *HttpError* configuration, since it works where I return a [HttpNotFoundResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpnotfoundresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) from a controller.

Then I realized that this is not *HttpErrors*, but the older *CustomErrors*. And the *CustomErrors* has obviously no knowledge of *HttpErrors*.

**The "bug"**

So what is happening is that [Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set to true and since no *CustomErrors* are defined, it returns the detailed 404 response. At this point we would like *HttpErrors* to kick in, but it wont because of *TrySkipIisCustomErrors* now is set to true.

And we can't use *CustomErrors* either, since this would bring us back to the issues with repugnant error redirections.

And the reason that returning [HttpNotFoundResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpnotfoundresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) works is because it will not trigger a runtime error, only return a 404-result which *HttpErrors* will intercept as expected, as long as we avoid to set [Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true.

**How should/could this be handled/resolved?**

I'm thinking that *[System.Web.HttpResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx).ReportRuntimeError* should not be allowed to set [Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true by default, since we have another errorhandling module dependent on this. Thus, this method needs to be aware of any [HttpErrors](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors) configuration as well, either by avoiding setting *TrySkipIisCustomErrors* to true if we have any [CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) configuration, or that it handles the *HttpErrors* configuration together with the *CustomErrors* configuration.

Or have I missed some secret magic to resolve this?

Comment: Well, as far as I investigated you can simply not combine CustomErrors with HttpErrors and have it functioning as expected. What I ended up with was turning of CustomErrors completely, and instead adding a HttpModule that checks the status code of the response and replaces any error response by calling my error controller directly. I also added a flag that we can use to define debug-mode, where it will only pass out the existing detailed error response without replacing it with our custom error.

Comment: did you tried using "Send Errors To Browser" and **Error Pages -> 500 -> Edit Feature Settings -> "Detailed Errors"** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5 ?

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling for several days to solve this problem and I think the only valid solution is the one posted [here](https://forums.asp.net/post/5727037.aspx) (An answer by [Starain chen](https://forums.asp.net/members/Starain%20chen%20-%20MSFT.aspx) to the same question posted by @Alex on forums.asp.net):

(I've slightly modified the code)

## The code

### Create a custom handle error attribute

```
public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute {
    public override void OnException (ExceptionContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled) {
            return;
        }

        var httpException = new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception);
        var httpStatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();

        switch ((HttpStatusCode) httpStatusCode) {
            case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
            case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }

        if (!ExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(filterContext.Exception)) {
            return;
        }

        // if the request is AJAX return JSON else view.
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest") {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new {
                    error = true,
                    message = filterContext.Exception.Message
                }
            };
        }
        else {
            var controllerName = (String) filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = (String) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult {
                ViewName = String.Format("~/Views/Hata/{0}.cshtml", httpStatusCode),
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model),
                TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
            };
        }

        // TODO: Log the error by using your own method

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
}
```

### Use this custom handle error attribute in `App_Start/FilterConfig.cs`

```
public class FilterConfig {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters (GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new CustomHandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

### Handle the remaining exceptions in `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_Error () {
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException ?? new HttpException((Int32) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Internal Server Error", exception);
    var httpStatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();

    Response.Clear();

    var routeData = new RouteData();

    routeData.Values.Add("Controller", "Error");
    routeData.Values.Add("fromAppErrorEvent", true);
    routeData.Values.Add("ErrorMessage", httpException.Message);
    routeData.Values.Add("HttpStatusCode", httpStatusCode);

    switch ((HttpStatusCode) httpStatusCode) {
            case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
            case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
            case HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", httpStatusCode.ToString());
                break;

            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "General");
                break;
        }

    Server.ClearError();

    IController controller = new Controllers.ErrorController();

    // TODO: Log the error if you like

    controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

### Create an `ErrorController`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ErrorController : Controller {
    protected override void OnActionExecuting (ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        var errorMessage = RouteData.Values["ErrorMessage"];
        var httpStatusCode = RouteData.Values["HttpStatusCode"];

        if (errorMessage != null) {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = (String) errorMessage;
        }

        if (httpStatusCode != null) {
            ViewBag.HttpStatusCode = Response.StatusCode = (Int32) httpStatusCode;
        }

        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }

    [ActionName("403")]
    public ActionResult Error403 () {
        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("404")]
    public ActionResult Error404 () {
        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("500")]
    public ActionResult Error500 () {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult General () {
        return View();
    }
}
```

### Create views

Create views for the actions in `ErrorController`. (`403.cshtml`, `404.cshtml`, `500.cshtml` and `General.cshtml`)

## Why do I think this is the only valid solution?

1. It handles both ASP.NET MVC and IIS-level errors (Assuming IIS7+ and integrated pipeline)
2. It returns valid http status codes. (Not 302 or 200)
3. It returns `200 OK` if I navigate to the error page directly: I'd like to get `200 OK` if I navigate to `/error/404`.
4. I can adjust the error page content. (Using `ViewBag.ErrorMessage`)
5. If the client makes an erroneous AJAX request and expects json data (within the actions of controllers) he/she will be served with a json data with the appropriate status code.

Comment: What settings do you user for system.web/customErrors and system.webServer/httpErrors?  Trying to get these just right so that our error responses aren't replaced by IIS, but also critical exceptions don't passthru detailed info is challenging.

Comment: @AaronLS Choosing "Integrated Pipeline" mode in application pool settings and probably `<customErrors mode="Off" />` is required, but no `httpErrors` is needed.

Comment: I copied this character for character, but all the error responses started coming back rendered by the browser (Firefox and Chrome) as plain HTML. In fact, inspecting the source of the response, the entire body of the response was wrapped in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, the browser debug tab showed the response to `mydomain.com/a` (or any other non-routed path) as type `plain` rather than `text/html` for some reason. I'm not sure why; debugging, `Response.ContentType` is still correctly "text/html". On a whim I added `Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");` to the Global.asax code immediately after the `Response.Clear()` line and that resolved the issue.

Comment: @killa-byte The difference between the value of `Response.ContentType` and what you see in browser dev tools network tab might indicate an unexpected removal of response headers somewhere. IMHO `Response.Clear()` shouldn't do that, because there's another method for that: `Response.ClearHeaders()`. I don't know, I'm confused just like you. Can you inspect the contents of `Response.Headers` before and after `Response.Clear()`?

Answer (score 3):

Just like you, I think ASP.NET shouldn't set TrySkipIisCustomErrors or may add an option so we can avoid it.

As a workaround, I built an ASPX page that is able to transfer the query to an ASP.NET MVC Controller.

**ErrorHandler.aspx.cs**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ErrorHandler.aspx.cs" Inherits="Guillaume.ErrorHandler" %>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Get status code
  var queryStatusCode = Request.QueryString.Get("code");
  int statusCode;
  if (!int.TryParse(queryStatusCode, out statusCode))
  {
    var lastError = Server.GetLastError();
    HttpException ex = lastError as HttpException;
    statusCode = ex == null ? 500 : ex.GetHttpCode();
  }
  Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

  // Execute a route
  RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
  string controllerName = Request.QueryString.Get("controller") ?? "Errors";
  routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
  routeData.Values.Add("action", Request.QueryString.Get("action") ?? "Index");

  var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
  IController controller = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
  controller.Execute(requestContext);
}
```

**Usage in web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="/Content/ErrorHandler.aspx">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Content/ErrorHandler.aspx?code=404&amp;controller=Errors&amp;action=NotFound" />
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The behavior is correct on regular browser request : the error page is shown when there is an error and the error code is returned.
It's also correct on an AJAX/Web API request : the error page is NOT returned. We get a parsable error in JSON or XML.

You may add a `httpErrors` section if you want non-ASP.NET errors to be redirected to your custom errors.

Comment: I combined the solution offered here with http://stackoverflow.com/a/5536676/2310818 to take care of all sorts of errors whether caused due to unknown route, unknown controller, unknown action, HttpNotFound() result returned by the controller action, and HttpException thrown by a controller. I achieved all of this while achieving correct status codes (404, 500) depending on type of error code.

Comment: I prefer this over the other answer (which adds a custom ErrorHandler attribute and adds an error handler in Global.asax) because you can then still use the Web.config customErrors and httpErrors configuration as you would with static files (and thus configure and toggle the customErrors mode On/Off as you need it.