# ASPNET HttpErrors redirect to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis, web-config

In my web config I have this setting:

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultPath="/Error/Error/ErrorHandler/404" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

I would like to redirect all IIS errors to go to my own controller and action. However I get the error:

`The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.`

However, If I try to redirect specific error codes to my controller, it will work. E.g:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
      <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Error/ErrorHandler/404"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

How can I change my default redirect to go to my controller/action?

Comment: have tried reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216158/the-requested-page-cannot-be-accessed-because-the-related-configuration-data-for

Comment: @jamiedanq Yeah I did and it's not my issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is not possible. `responseMode` only supports:

1. `File` for unprocessed files, like .html
2. `ExecuteURL` supports .aspx files
3. `Redirect` to redirect to a different page which is not recommended from a SEO perspective.

You could try the answer from mono blaine in this post: [CustomErrors vs HttpErrors - A significant design flaw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465261/customerrors-vs-httperrors-a-significant-design-flaw)