# How to end request with 404 in an IHttpModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I'm writing a new IHttpModule. I would like to invalidate certain requests with 404 using a `BeginRequest` event handler. How do I terminate the request and return a 404?

Comment: This has your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499817/what-is-the-proper-way-to-send-an-http-404-response-from-an-asp-net-mvc-action -- throw an HttpException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly set the status code to 404 like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404; 
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Response will stop executing.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 404; 
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
throw new HttpException(404, "File Not Found");
```

Comment: Why would throwing be better than just doing a `Response.StatusCode = 404; Response.End()` ?

Comment: If you want the IIS generated html that usually accompanies a 404, use the exception

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", l_notFoundPageUrl);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Assign l_notFoundPageUrl to your 404 page.

Comment: Would a `Response.StatusCode = 404;` not be enough?